# In a document library : group by view with manage metadata Navigation problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata

I encountered a problem while configuring a document library using a group by view with the Managed Metadata filtering and navigation.
Under Key filters option ( Search Option)

- all the documents appear under group by, even the ones that does not belong to the search
- In the other hand, the number in bracket shows the correct number of documents that should be shown.

Anyone have encountered same problem with managed metadata navigation?

Answer (score 0):

This was a SharePoint bug that had been addressed by a previous SharePoint 2013 CU, but it still currently has one scenario where it occurs, if the Group By column is a Lookup field.

More details here: https://sharepointycl.wordpress.com/2017/03/24/wrong-results-from-metadata-filtering-in-grouped-list-view